# Как узнать прошли ли 30 секунд?

Tags: android

Есть PinActivity, в котором форма для ввода пароля, мне нужно определить, что если прошли 30 секунд, то ввести пароль, иначе запустить приложение. Как установить проверку на время?

Comment: есть класс `Timer` и есть еще `Sheduler`.

Comment: Записать время в переменную, когда нужно проверить прошло/не прошло сравнить с текущим. Или Вам нужно чтобы через 30 сек что-то выполнилось автоматически?

Comment: Нет, не обязательно, для этого можно использовать Date?

Comment: @АнтонЛялин можно использовать разницу во времени системы, также если вам придется писать логику под  эту дату в дальнейшем, и спустя время вам необходимо будет хранить переменную Date в памяти. Зная первое и второе, это приличная дыра уязвимости которая позволит или входить всегда без пароля или делать необходимые манипуляция для подбора PIN, сбрасывая ввод пароля. Нет необходимости объяснять, как долго подбираются 4х значный PIN. Поэтому я считаю это неверный подход. Таймер в отдельном потоке, локальная переменная, и слушатель на данный метод, который получает только ответ, выглядит лучше.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один из вариантов:
Создаём переменные:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler(); //Создаем handler для выполнения кода с задержкой
private final int DELAY = 30; //Задержка 30 секунд
private Runnable run; //Выполняем данный runnable после задержки
```

Добавляем в onCreate (либо другой метод на старте):

```
//Создаем runnable
run = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //30 секунд прошли, запускаем приложение
    }
};
```

Запускаем таймер:

```
handler.postDelayed(run, DELAY*1000);
```

Добавляем в метод проверки/ввода пароля (то есть пароль ввели, 30 секунд не прошло):

```
handler.removeCallback(run);
// Последующие действия
```